# How to draw portion of a sprite in libGDX

Tags: libgdx, sprites

Let's say i have a sprite like this:
[image]

and i want to draw the lower portion of it, only the yellow color..
Initially the sprite has dimensions 10x10, i want it to be drawn 10x3

Do i have to redimension both the sprite and the texture region to mantain proportion between the two?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for [masking](https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/LibGDX-Masking).

Comment: My intent is to draw the life bar of a character. I have the complete bar sprite and i want to draw the portion related to the "health" of the character. So, if i have 30% health, i want th sprite to be drawn 30% tall but if i use the sprite.setSize method, it stretches the texture. Can you explain how do i use masking?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the specifics in Libdgx well enough to explain them myself. I've written [an answer explaining the general concept of clipping/masking](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/69693/7804) though, which might help with conceptual understanding.

Comment: A similar question to this was asked recently: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/98470/libgdx-easy-way-to-draw-partial-sprites

Comment: I found your answer on the other question very useful BUT i have the problem that the sprite was created as a textureregion of an imageAtlas so with frame.getTexture() i get all the atlas and not only the region realted to that sprite!!

Comment: @Catta_ Yes, you get the whole texture, but the sprite itself contains the regions bounds, which you can reuse with small modifications to, for example, only draw the lower half of the sprite. See the frame.getRegion*() parameters in those examples.

Comment: @Catta_ I answered with an example that should cover your particular scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I gave in [the other question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/98470/libgdx-easy-way-to-draw-partial-sprites) doesn't quite do exactly what you want, but the following example might help. You still need to re-proportion both the heights to do what you want, but you also need to move the input data region down to compensate for the smaller window:

```
spriteBatch.draw(
    sprite.getTexture(),
    x,
    y,
    width / 2,
    height / 2,
    width,
    height * 0.3f,                                        /* Scale output height */
    sprite.getScaleX(),
    sprite.getScaleY(),
    0,
    sprite.getRegionX(),
    sprite.getRegionY() + sprite.getRegionWidth() * 0.7f, /* Move input data position */
    sprite.getRegionWidth(),
    (int)((float)sprite.getRegionWidth() * 0.3f),         /* Scale input height */
    false,
    false);
```